# FisherHypergeometricDistribution and WalleniusHypergeometricDistribution, how to specify boundary conditions

Tags: distributions

I'm trying to write a function that consists of a noncentral hypergeometric distribution. When I'm passing a set of parameters to the function, the following boundary problems occur:

```
PDF[FisherHypergeometricDistribution[2, 0, 2, 1], 0], 
PDF[FisherHypergeometricDistribution[2, 0, 2, 1], 1], 
PDF[FisherHypergeometricDistribution[2, 0, 2, 1], 2],...
```

The built-in Fisher's hypergeometric distribution function require the second parameter to be a positive integer, but I sometimes pass 0 into it. So here I have to handle exceptions.

Logically it is clear that if the second parameter of the inner Hypergeometric Distribution function is 0, the result of the outer PDF function depends on its last parameter. If it is 0, the probability should be 1, otherwise it should be 0.

So I need a way to tell mathematica that

```
PDF[FisherHypergeometricDistribution[2, 0, 2, 1], 0]=1
PDF[FisherHypergeometricDistribution[2, 0, 2, 1], 1]=0, 
PDF[FisherHypergeometricDistribution[2, 0, 2, 1], 2]=0
```

,...etc

Could someone please help me with this problem?
Thank you very much!!!